# what are the security best practices with twilio and firebase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-s3, twilio

I was looking for a tutorial or stackoverflow thread but I couldn't find a best practice how I can do it.

I have an ios swift app and I want to send sms if a user create an add a record in Firebase, like sending an invitation to someone or doing something which could affect other user.

According to some post on the internet and on your blog I need a server side script which makes it safe and I don't have to store those information in my swift code. Like here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/11/how-to-send-an-sms-from-ios-in-swift.html

Currently I don't have a server. Only thing that I have is a Firebase account.

What is a best practice regarding security? For instance shall I create a webserver on AWS or just a AWS S3 bucket would be enough and shall I store those credentials or php codes there?

I'm quite new in the these things and unfortunately I don't know whom shall I ask.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases), which allow you to run server-side code with just your Firebase account. Unfortunately, calling to Twilio requires a paid Firebase account.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have already seen that option with the cloud function, but it would send notification. I would like to send sms.

Comment: also I'm wondering why does someone downgrade a question. I have already tried to find an answer everywhere and I would be interested how others solved the problem. Instead of downgrade a question they should say what their problem is and I cloud clarify it better.

Comment: Cloud Functions can be used to send SMS messages. But it would still be through a 3rd party service, such as Twilio.

Comment: thanks Frank. let me check it out.

Comment: I don't know for sure but the down vote was most likely because of three things. There's no code, the question really isn't about a specific coding issue and it's opinion based. All of those fall outside the guidelines of this site. It's not a bad question, it's just not a good question here. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when you do have a coding question, post it here and we'll take a look!